# How do I compare value from one row against all other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare every single row against all other rows in pandas.

Having this DataFrame:

```
index     entity

a           1
            2
            3

b           3
            3
            9

c           10
            0
            1

d           9
            3
            0
```

I want a match on:

`[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]` *(these are indexes)* because 1,2,3 *(these are values in a column)* exists in every column. Also, how can I actually count repetitive matches? Example, index A finds a pair with all values (one, two, three), index C only with 1 value (zero).

I understand I need to hold row with index A in variable, and then compare it against all other rows in a loop. After this done, I move to row with index B and repeat this action for every other row, including row with index A.

How do I hold one row in memory and check it against all other rows?

Output can be in format of a list [0,1], [0,2], where numbers are indexes.

That's sort of pseudo-code I have right now in mind:

```
var = [x for x in e_dataframe.entity]

for rows in e_dataframe.entity:
    for x in var:
        if x == rows:
            print('match', x, ' and ', rows)
        else:
            print('not match ', x , ' and ', rows)
```

Where `entity` what be our column with numerical values above.

Of course this is wrong, i don't match anything. I somehow cannot wrap my head around writing this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with somehow mixed approach. But in a way it's just looking for duplicated values.

First I've created new column with True/False depending if the entity is duplicated (found numerous times). Then I iterate through tuple of entity and it's boolean value. I've set condition to check if entity is indeed repeated, then I entity value as a mask for pandas dataframe to find all other identical entities.

```
df_words['dup_check'] = df_words.entity.duplicated(keep=False)
indexes_list = []

for rows in zip(df_words.entity, df_words.dup_check):
    if rows[1] == True:
            i_list = df_words[df_words.entity == rows[0]]
            indexes_list.append(i_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but here is a version of your code that runs. Please note some small changes to the variable names.

```
var = [x for x in df["entity"]]
#print(var)

for row in df["entity"]:
    #print(row)
    for x in var:
        if x == row:
            print('match', x, ' and ', row)
        else:
            print('not match ', x , ' and ', row)
```

Are you trying to find duplicates? I also don't understand the logic behind the index pairs you mention.

Comment: Oh, I made wrong condition in if statement, yours is correct one, I'll edit my question. Yeah, now it finds matches, but it's still not I want to accomplish. First, notice that DF is in form of MultiIndexed data (each index holds 3 values). Second, I don't try to find duplicates, i try to find intersections (or something similar to this). By intersection I mean "Index[N] row Value['x'] is found also in Indexes[N+len(df)]".